# How to configure RAID 5 with different size drives?

Tags: windows-7, raid-5

If I have 3 different drives, for example 10GB, 20GB and 30GB. I would like to configure RAID 5. What would be the size of data disk and parity disk in the array?

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to RAID-5 the lowest value.
The result will be 10GB-Data1, 10GB-Data2, 10GB-Parity, that's **20GB of usable space.**
Drive 1 will be fully  utilized, drive 2 will have 10GB available and drive 3 will have 20GB available.